# Toggle not functioning upon clicking

Tags: html, css

is there anyway I can make a div stay a background of black once active?

Basically, I have:

```
<div class="navigation-box">
    <div class="sidehead"><i class="lock"></i><span class="title">User Account</span> <span class="toggle">+</span></div>
        <ul class="navLinks">
            <li>11SS</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And once hovered, it shows the background of black. But what I want it to do, is remain black once clicked.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfbsjxy7/)

a perfect example is this layout http://cdn2.mosaicpro.biz/smart/php/admin/projects_grid.html?v=v1.0.0-rc1 (simply click the link "access" and see how it is)

That's what I'm trying to do. I thought I could take it doing CSS, but it's not seeming to work apparently. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm in the process of writing an answer, but since you're already using JavaScript for other things, why not use JavaScript to change the color to black onclick?

Comment: @TylerH you mean something like `$('.blah').click(function() {
     $(this).css('background', 'black');
 });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add an active class when you click. As the code below.

```
$(function () {
    $('.navigation-title').click(function () {
        $('.navigation-item').removeClass('active');                    
        $('.navgation-links').slideUp('active');
        $('.navigation-title .toggle').text('+');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).find('.toggle').text('-');
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    });
});
```

I fork the fiddle and changed the structure a bit.

[Forked JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8hd6L8yu/)

Comment: Surprised this was the accepted answer when it's using a language that wasn't specified in the post or the tags, and no comments were given

Comment: I just edited her code to suit her problem. But if so, I can create a complete navigation steps for you to also use. ;) You're welcome @kris, just wanted to help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use only CSS, then I think this should be possible using the infamous CSS checkbox hack. Basically, you'll be using `input[type=checkbox]` to act as a sort of "binary" check: is the list item selected OR is it not?

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfbsjxy7/1/)**

A short explanation of what I've changed:

1. Added an `input[type=button]` element before each `.sidehead` div element.
2. Moved the buttons `9999px` up and left, so that they'll be hidden off-screen.
3. Changed each `.sidehead` div element to a `label` that is linked to its preceding button. This way you click the label and it will check the button.

Since buttons can be *unchecked* as well as *checked*, this means you can click the label again and remove the color change, in effect giving the "unselected" look.

The only drawback to this method is that, since your JavaScript hides one list item when you click on another, it results in awkward un-colored labels when you click another label, so you'll have to update your JavaScript to automatically uncheck the checkbox of any list item that gets collapsed.

Here is the new HTML and CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navigation-box">
    <input type="checkbox" id="button1" />
    <label for="button1" class="sidehead"><i class="lock"></i><span class="title">User Account</span><span class="toggle">+</span>
    </label>
    <ul class="navLinks">
        <li>11SS</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333;
    background: #e1e0de;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation-body {
    clear: left;
    margin-top: 40%;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    left: -6%;
    right: -7%;
}
.sidehead {
    padding: 6px 6px 4px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}
.sidehead:hover {
    background: #191919;
}
.sidehead .lock {
    background: url('../images/lock.png') no-repeat center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top:-5px;
    margin-left:5%;
}
.sidehead:hover .lock {
    background: url("../images/lock-hover.png") no-repeat center;
}
.sidehead span.title {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
.sidehead:hover {
    color: white;
}
span.toggle {
    float: right;
    margin-top:3px;
    display: inline-block;
    right:4%;
    left:90%;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.navLinks {
    margin:0;
    padding-left:35%;
    background: #191919;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    top: -9999px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidehead {
    background: #191919;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: I LOVE the checkbox hack. Good thinking! +1.

Comment: @TylerH Love the Tut, and thank you for that. However I did some sorting around on stack, and found something that helped, but when I don't want it to be active, it still shows the black bar. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfbsjxy7/2/

Comment: @kris That extra JavaScript is just changing the color for all elements with class `sidehead` to black onclick (it's doing the first half of what I suggested in my earlier comment above). To use this method successfully, you'd also have to switch non-active elements back to their original CSS styling onclick as well (additionally you can add an if statement to do this only if they've been clicked before).